# How to fix S7 edge performance degrade after Oreo update?

Tags: samsung, downgrade, samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge

My S7 edge (G9350) upgraded to Oreo for a month and the performance really degraded. I did factory reset to my S7 but  nothing improved.

I want to flash my S7 edge G9350 from Oreo to Nougat/Marshmallow but did not succeed  because of FRP .I don't understand why I got locked by FRP even  when I entered correct Google account ( now my S7 working is functional except the performance )

Are there any possible ways to flash my ROM to Marshmallow ?

Comment: It is unlikely you will succeed because of [Anti Roll Back feature](https://www.xda-developers.com/android-pie-rollback-protection/). I am not sure if this feature is implemented on your device but  Knox feature of Samsung makes it more difficult. Nevertheless, you can search on forums like XDA on ways to flash a custom ROM

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to downgrade as bootlader is now on revision 7 (if I recall correctly) and Marshmallow/Nougat uses way older ones. So an official update won't be an option.

The other method is to use a custom ROM from XDA (you'll find many there), but be advised that that'll void your warranty and could brick your device (tho unlikely).

If you want to use a custom ROM, you can either go for an old TouchWiz ROM or (like I did on my S7) use an AOSP-based ROM. Presonaly I use LineageOS 16.0(9.0), but 15.1 (8.1) is preferred for stability as 16.0 is still beta. I'd recommend you use a custom AOSP ROM over an old TouchWiz ROM as those old ROMs don't have security patches and using an old Android version is never a good idea, not only because of security, but also you're just downgrading your phone in terms of features.